# Error while assigning product to category?

Tags: magento-1.8, database

I am trying to assign category to product through a simple script and it's throwing an error i have tried doing through admin panel and it works there but as i have to do this for thousands of products i can't do it through the admin panel.

Here is myscript

```
<?php


$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(55181);
$product->setCategoryIds(array(437));
$product->save();

?>
```

Error :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '55181-0-1-100.0000-0' for key 'E8AB433B9ACB00343ABB312AD2FAB087'' in /path/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php:1348
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your script is working in the admin context by including something like

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is directly caused by your script. More like a result of issue in your database. Run the following from the commandline. It might fix the issue as it tries to repair any issues with your database.

```
mysqlcheck -u[username] -p[password] -h[host] --check --auto-repair --all-databases
```

Answer (score 1):

You could import those relation by using my module FastSimpleImport (https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport) which is basically a wrapper for ImportExport but with some added functionality like the import of product-category relations. The code would look like:

```
$data = array();
$data[] = array(
    '_root' => 'Default Category',
    '_category' => 'Test2',
    '_sku' => '4711',
    'position' => 1
);
$data[] = array(
    '_root' => 'Default Category',
    '_category' => 'Test2',
    '_sku' => '0815',
    'position' => 2
);
$data[] = array(
    '_root' => 'Default Category',
    '_category' => 'Test2/Test3',
    '_sku' => '0815',
    'position' => 1
);

/** @var $import AvS_FastSimpleImport_Model_Import */
$import = Mage::getModel('fastsimpleimport/import');
try {
    $import->processCategoryProductImport($data);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print_r($import->getErrorMessages());
}
```

Of course you can generate the array as you want.